# SoapException Not Caught in try catch

Tags: vb.net, wcf, web-services, try-catch, soapexception

Take the following try-catch statement in a `WCF-Service`

```
    Try
        'Here some method is being called.
        Return myBs.PerformDailyUpdate()

    Catch ex As Exception 'Exception is not being caught here
        If service IsNot Nothing AndAlso service.HasWarnings Then
            TextFileTracer.Write(String.Format("Warning in method: '{0}'.", name))
            TextFileTracer.Write(service.GetWarnings)
        End If
        Try
            TextFileTracer.Write("Error in dbmanager: " & service.HasErrors.ToString)
        Catch ex2 As Exception
        End Try
        TextFileTracer.Write(String.Format("Error in method: '{0}'.", name))
        TextFileTracer.Write(ex.Message & vbCrLf & ex.StackTrace)
    End Try
End Function 'Exception shows here while debugging
```

In that method (`PerformDailyUpdate`) an `ASMX-Webservice (.Net 2.0)` is being called. This webservice throws occassionaly an `SOAPException` caused from a method being called from that webservice.yet somehow this SOAPException is nog being caught by the method above.

**My Question:** Why isn't the SOAPException being Caught? Are there some characteristics that seperates a SOAP-Exception from normal 'exceptions' generated (that in turn cause it not be caught)?

**Note**: The code written here is not mine. So Please don't judge me on it

**ExceptionMessage (First part)**

```
  System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Unexpected application error: SqlException.
  ADF.ExceptionHandling.GlobalExceptions.UnexpectedException: Unexpected application error: SqlException.
  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near ')'.
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
  ....
```

Thanks

```
Scheme (how this clarifies the situation somewhat):

Internal DailyTriggerMechanism  -----> WCF - Service  ----->  ASMX-Webservice        ----> DB2/SQL
                                     (Origin code above)    (Exception being thrown)
```

Inside the WCF-Service the data recieved is being manipulated to fill specific tables. The AMSX-Webservice may not change in this situation.

Comment: Is this a case where the SOAP error happens on the host, but you're trying to catch it on the client? It's hard to tell from the description.

Comment: Ill edit my post to clarify the situation.

Comment: First of all, if use a Service Reference (and you _should_) then you will get a `FaultException` or maybe `FaultException<T>`, not a `SoapException`. Second, if `catch (Exception ex)` doesn't catch the exception, then it means that no exception was thrown.

Comment: added the the first part of the given exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a normal exception should be able to catch that unhandled error you're listed, but you might try a SOAP-specific, and/or SQL-related exception, in addition to your regular exception.

Like:

```
try {
    //your failing code
} 
catch (SOAPException se) 
{
   //your response    }
catch (SQLException sqle) 
{
   //your response     
}
catch (Exception e) 
{
   //your response     
}
```

Comment: Will try to do this. Perhaps an idiotic and/or stupid question (just wanna cover all my bases here). Image i have a custom exception inherited from SOAPException. Where will it be caught? at the catch soapexpection or the catch exception?

Comment: If it's a custom exception, you'll have to catch the specific exception they're throwing using the exception definition (class) they've created. That would be found in a DLL they're using. You'd have to reference it in your project to use (catch) it. But anything that inherits from the base class exception (what they'd should have done if they created a custom exception class) should be catchable by a regular try, catch statment using Exception e.

Comment: Same thing with a custom class that inherits SoapException.

Comment: Thanks voor the explanation!